# USB not registering on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, formatting

I have a usb with a hidden cdfs partition that I want to purge, but when I plug it into my linux box, it doesn't register. fdisk -l only shows my hard drives, and the usb doesn't auto-mount. I pulled the USB out, plugged it in and ran dmesg to get the following lines:

```
[36952.162722] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues
[36953.005657] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[36953.090245] scsi89 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[36954.093760] scsi 89:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Contour   4.13 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[36954.095570] scsi 89:0:0:1: CD-ROM            SanDisk  Cruzer Contour   4.13 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[36954.098583] sd 89:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[36954.103342] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 8x/40x writer xa/form2 cdda tray
[36954.103950] sr 89:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[36954.168330] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues
```

Comment: Did you mount it Manually?

Comment: Nope. All I did was plug it in.

Comment: try this commands:
1. `mkdir directory`
2. `mount /dev/sdb ~/directory`
Feed back the error

Comment: When the USB isn't plugged in, I get:
`mount: special device /dev/sdb does not exist`
When it is plugged in, I get:
`mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb`

Comment: First you must plug your USB after. sorry try 1. mount /dev/sdb1 ~/directory ... I forgot to write **1** . test it and feed back here

Comment: I only get `mount: special device /dev/sdb2 does not exist` with that one, even when the USB is plugged in.

Comment: Did you test sdb1 ? You can use fdisk /dev/sdb to see your USB partition and file system,

Comment: I guess you are new to Linux, If problem still exist and you can't use your USB tell me here to write SIMPLE tutorial to how to mount your USB just for you.

Comment: Oh, I did sdb1 as well, to a similar result. fdisk /dev/sdb gives `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found`, and fdisk -l only shows me my main hard drive. One wee thing about the USB: cdfs is supposed to make it behave like a CD when plugged in. It came formatted like that when I got it, and I'm trying to kill it with fire. It does not register as a CD when I plug it into my Linux box.

Comment: Ok, Last way ( i think ) install ntfs-3g on your linux,
1. if debian base : `apt-get update && apt-get install ntfs-3g`
2. if redhat base : `yum install ntfs-3g`
3. Or download its source file then install it,
after installing finished reboot your system and boot it again now plug your USB, it must mount automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8434/discussion-between-davidos-and-sepahrad-salour)

Comment: Ok, no problem...

Comment: try ejecting the "CD" that Linux thinks it's part of the USB stick. `eject /dev/sr1`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Attempting to mount/use gparted after ejecting still doesn't show the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

From your dmesg output, the USB stick is seen as a read-only device.

Please, see [USB memory stick presents as two storage devices](https://superuser.com/questions/367674/usb-memory-stick-presents-as-two-storage-devices).